# How can I make Apple's mixer audio unit on iOS not do an audio fade?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am using The Amazing Audio Engine to simply play an audio file, but I find that when the channel starts playing, there is some automatic fade in happening.

You can see the top waveform is the output of my iPad, and the bottom waveform is the actual raw audio file.  There is definitely a 30ms microfade being done.

[image]

There is nothing doing that within the amazing audio engine library, so it's something internally happening from apple's mixer audio unit.  Is there any way to turn off this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the AudioFilePlayer (used by TAAE) uses the [Extended Audio File Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/) under the hood.  ExtAudioFileRef will do that on the first read after a seek if there is any de-coding or sample rate conversion.  I had to use the [Audio File Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/) directly to get ride of the implicit fading.